# Change layout when width is less than X pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, responsive-design

I am developing a website using Laravel and Bootstrap. The website looks alright on desktop and mobile (first and third picture), but it looks ugly on the second picture, when I start reducing the width and it hasn't switched to mobile view yet.

**Desktop view:**

[image]

**Distorted view (which I don't want):**

[image]

**Mobile view:**

[image]

**Here is the code that I currently have:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<?php
$loggedIn = Auth::check();
$user = Auth::user();
?>

<style>
    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust if needed) */
    .row.content {height: 1500px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .sidenav {
            height: auto;
            padding: 15px;
        }
        .row.content {height: auto;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
        .col-sm-2, col-sm-8 { display: flex; flex-flow: column; }
        #one { order: 3; }
        #two { order: 1;  }
        #three { order: 2; }
    }
</style>

@section('content')
    @if ($loggedIn)
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row content">

                <div class="col-xs-2 sidenav" id="one">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="card card-default">
                                <div class="card-header">Navigation</div>

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section2">Messages</a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section3">People</a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section3">Photos</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-8" id="two">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="card card-default">
                                <div class="card-header">Recent Posts</div>

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    Here will be recent posts.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2 sidenav" id="three">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="card card-default">
                                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    You are logged in as <strong>{{$user->name}}</strong>.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row content">

                <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" id="one">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="card card-default">
                                <div class="card-header">Navigation</div>

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section2">Messages</a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section3">People</a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#section3">Photos</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-8" id="two">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="card card-default">
                                <div class="card-header">Recent Posts</div>

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <strong>You are not logged in!</strong><hr>
                                    Here will be recent posts.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" id="three">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="card card-default">
                                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                                <div class="card-body">
                                    You are not logged in!
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endsection
```

**The question is:**

What do I need to do/add to force the website to switch to **mobile view** when the width is less or equal to `1105px`?

Comment: There's no `1105px` breakpoint in Bootstrap.

Comment: What should I do if I want to change the view when the width reaches the breakpoint that is close to 1105px, but must be larger than that?

Comment: You already have some `@media` queries in your css. Have you tried adding another query and styling for that breakpoint manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try playing around with the columns `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg` etc. Don't be afraid to use more than one column in a div - for example you have:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" id="one">
```

What about if you did something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidenav" id="one">
```

So this is saying in a small or extra small layout, go fullwidth. On a medium layout, use a quarter of the parent/row, on a large layout use a 6th of the parent/row.

Be sure to make the other columns match 12 in total for sm, md, lg, xs etc.

Comment: Thank you! I played a little with this classes and now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own version of [`Bootstrap 3`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/) with the wanted breakpoints and just press `compile and download` and you are good to go. Check the breakpoints under `Container sizes`, just search for the keyword, once u get on the link.